# wine crash at script launching msmoney

Tags: wine

recent upgrades to Ubuntu 20.04 and Wine 5.0, the script to launch Msmoney under Wine that worked for a along time run correctly once and crashed at the 2nd attempt with the message:

002e:err:winsock:WSAIoctl -> SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE request failed with status 0x2733
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\windows\system32\version.exe" not found

the script is:
#!/bin/bash
wine ~/.../MSMONEY.EXE

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You have a clear error message. Does that file exist in that location? "C:\windows\system32\version.exe" not found

Comment: "C:\windows\system32\version.exe" does not exist and never did, even when msmoney worked correctly under Ubuntu18  and Wine3;

Comment: But now you have 20.04 things must be different that is also a very old version of wine.

Comment: i am doing some more tests and attempts, encouraging so far  but still a long way before conclusions, WIne 5.0 is not so old ...